# Element showing on screen but only added to DOM after Inspection or clicking

Tags: python, selenium, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use selenium to download reports from Google Ads, the script is working fine until I try to click the Campaign-wide target button in the image, It's not showing in the DOM and selenium can't see it until I click/inspect it that it's accessible.  [image]

I tried to switch frames and search for it but to no avail, I have only two frames when I try

`iframes = b.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//iframe")`

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv


class Bot:
    def __init__(self, user_data_dir=None, profile_dir=None, csv_filename=None):
        self.__service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.user_data_dir = user_data_dir 
        self.profile_dir = profile_dir
        self.__options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.__options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={self.user_data_dir}")
        self.__options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={self.profile_dir}")
        self.csv_filename = csv_filename or "data.csv"

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.__service, options=self.__options)
 
    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("https://ads.google.com")
        sleep(1)

        try:
            # get the sign in button and click it
            sign_in_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header-topbar"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/a')
            sign_in_btn.click()
            sleep(2)

            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # if the sign in button is not found, try clicking the drawer menu button and then the sign in button
            drawer_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header-drawer"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/button')
            drawer_btn.click()
            sleep(2)
            
            sign_in_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header-topbar"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/a')
            sign_in_btn.click()
            sleep(2)

        finally:
            accnt_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/root/div[2]/nav-view-loader/multiaccount-view/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/material-list/material-list-item[4]/div/div[1]')
            accnt_btn.click()
            sleep(5)

    
    def do(self):

        self.login()
        # get the campaigns button dropdown button and click it
        campaigns_drpdwn_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/root/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/awsm-skinny-nav/nav/div[1]/div[3]/awsm-skinny-nav-item[1]/a/material-ripple')
        campaigns_drpdwn_btn.click()
        sleep(2)

        # TODO get all the campaigs lists and click on each one of them
        # get a certain campaign and click it
        campaign_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cmExtensionPoint-id"]/base-root/div/div[2]/div[1]/view-loader/campaign-view/tableview/div[6]/ess-table/ess-particle-table/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ess-cell[2]/campaign-name/campaign-name-generic/a')
        campaign_btn.click()
        sleep(2)

        # campaign more details button
        campaign_more_details_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/root/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/content-header/deferred-infosnack/infosnack/div/div[1]/review-panel-trigger/button/div[2]')
        campaign_more_details_btn.click()
        sleep(5)


        # get the bid strategy button, using the 'Maximize conversions' text as a span and click it
        campaign_bid_strategy_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Maximize conversions')]")
        campaign_bid_strategy_btn.click()
        sleep(4)

        # get the campaign simulator button and click it
        campaign_sim_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Campaign simulator')]")
        campaign_sim_btn.click()
        sleep(2)

        # get the campaign simulator target dropdown and click it [%, campaign wide target]
        campaign_sim_target_dropdn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Target scaling')]")
        campaign_sim_target_dropdn.click()
        sleep(2)

        campaign_wide_target_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Campaign-wide target')]")
        campaign_wide_target_btn.click()
        sleep(2)
```

I'm trying to get selenium to see the button, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share **ALL** your code including the links if possible

Comment: @Prophet thanks for replying, I'll Update the post for the code, the link is private as it requires my cookies

Comment: @Prophet I have updated the post to include the code

Comment: I see. generally, looks like that element is appearing after hovering or clicking the chart. But since we can't go to that page we are missing basic debugging details.

Comment: It's only added to the DOM when I click inspect on or click it not clicking the chart. yeah I guess it's hard without having access to the page, thanks for your reply

Comment: @Prophet I'm a bit noob using selenium, Do you know what usually can be the reasons for this besides iframes?

Comment: There are several possible things. I can't guess since I have no enough information. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was to simulate my interaction using **ActionChains** https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/,

Code:

```
select_click = ActionChains(self.driver)
select_click.move_to_element(campaign_sim_target_dropdn)
select_click.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
select_click.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
select_click.perform()
```

Then the element was added to the DOM and I was able to access it with XPATH